# SQLite Prepared Statement for Create Table error

Tags: sqlite

I'm running into an error trying to use a SQLite prepared statement:

```
create table RawRecord (?, ?, ?);
```

Calling sqlite3_prepare16_v2 gives me this error: `SQLITE_ERROR: SQLITE_ERROR[1]: near "?": syntax error`

I don't run into problems with prepared statements anywhere else (and have been using SQLite for many years).  I have tried to find whether prepared statements are simply not allowed for CREATE TABLE, but haven't found anyone saying that's the case.

If I build the create string manually and embed my column names, it works.  I prefer to use prepared statements simply because it makes things like quotes cleaner, and in this case the column names come from user data, so I don't know what they will be.

I can certainly work around this, but was hoping to understand why this is an error.

Help?

Comment: A single SQL statement is hardly enough to go on, but it seems like you are not calling `sqlite3_bind_text16` with the column definitions.

Comment: You can't use parameters for table or column names.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I assumed, but failed to find written anywhere.  It's nice to hear someone say it.

Comment: FWIW: it is in the [sqlite doc](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#varparam) [emphasis added]: _A "variable" or "parameter" token specifies a placeholder in the **expression** for a value that is filled in at runtime_